# How do I the change application name in volume levels?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, indicator-sound

When i try to change the volume levels individually for each application, the application name does not match the actual application its coming from.
Because of this. It is difficult to comfortably adjust volume levels as i don't know what tag meets what application.

[show here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqhmJ.png)

How can i change the tag name that represents the application or make them match?

I have tried using pulseaudio but the name still doesn't match the application its coming from.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ok so apparently. One "skype" belongs to Discord and the other "skype" tag belongs to Microsoft Teams